# Redux / Thunk / slice function not returning data for param call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

When I try to load a list of a users logs in my Redux store with Thunk / Slice for some reason it is saying fulfilled and not populating the store. I have checked my backend API and it is working correctly and when I refresh the page I the call is hitting the backend as console Is taking in the userID of the logged in user.

I can see the correct data in the action tab but nothing in the store and because I reference the useSelector to access the state I can't access the array I need.

Is there something obvious I am doing to place the array list in the correct part of the store? It is the first occasion where I am using a param for Thunk Redux data and it is being stored in the user part of the store as it is specific to the user so it is a bit different from before.

[image]

[image]

```
// load a users diveLog
export const requireUserDiveLogData = createAsyncThunk(
    'user/requireData', // action name
    // action expects to be called with the name of the field
    async (userID, thunkAPI) => {
        // you need to define a function to fetch the data by field name
        const response = await userDiveLogList(userID);
        // what we return will be the action payload
        return response.data;
    },
    {
        condition: (_, { getState }) => {
            const { user } = getState(); // returns redux state
            // check if there is already data by looking at the didLoadData property
            if (user.didLoadData) {
                // return false to cancel execution
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
)
```

reducer

```
export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        userDiveLogList: [],
        didLoadData: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        // picks up the pending action from the thunk
        [requireUserDiveLogData.pending.type]: (state) => {
            // set didLoadData to prevent unnecessary re-fetching
            state.didLoadData = true;
        },
        // picks up the success action from the thunk
        [requireUserDiveLogData.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
            // want to replace all lists, there are multiple ways to do this
            // I am returning a new state which overrides any properties
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            }
        },
```

diveLog.component

```
 const classes = useStyles

    const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.user);

    const userDiveLogList = useSelector(state => state.user.userDiveLogList);

    const [userDiveLog, setUserDiveLog] = useState({
        userDiveLogList: [],
        expanded: false
    })

    console.log(user.userID)
    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(requireUserDiveLogData(user.userID));
        console.log(user.userID)
    }, []);
```

Comment: can you please also show your `useSelector` usage?

Comment: It's added now. My problem is that the store isn't being populated where it looks it should go and I can see the data is has been loaded in the action. It looks like it has been named correctly.

Comment: You should put `[user.userID]` as the dependency of the `useEffect` but that's not your problem.  If an action is dispatched but the state isn't updated that sounds like a problem in the reducer.  But the code looks right to me because I wrote it :)  Try replacing that whole "fulfilled" reducer with `state.userDiveLogList = action.payload.userDiveLogList`.  Does that do anything?

Comment: If the top screenshot shows the state after the actions then `didLoadData` is never getting set to `true` either.  That should happen from the "pending" action.  I'm also noticing that there's an array `userPhotoList` in the dev tools that is never initialized in your reducer.  Is it possible that you have multiple `user` reducers?  And this isn't the one that's being used?